# Return information that my object implements IDisposable

Tags: c#

I have this class

```
public class MyClient : IMyClient, IMyClientAsync,IDisposable
```

I am writing a wrapper that returns `IMyClientAsync` like this:

```
IMyClientAsync GetClient()
{
   return new MyClient ();
}
```

But then anyone who is using this wrapper can't close the client in a `using` block like `using(var client = MyWrapper.GetClient()){}` since the information that object implements `IDisposable` is lost.

Is there any way to change it to be able to still close my client in a `using` block?

Comment: I think you need to return type `MyClient` instead of `IMyClientAsync`, since `MyClient` is the one actually implementing `IDisposable`. There's nothing here that shows `IMyClientAsync` implements `IDisposable`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible for interfaces to inherit from other interfaces, so rather than having `MyClient` inherit both `IMyClientAsync` and `IDisposable`, simply change `IMyClientAsync` to inherit from `IDisposable` instead like so:

```
public interface IMyClientAsync : IDisposable
{}

public class MyClient : IMyClient, IMyClientAsync
{}
```

This way, consumers of your code can wrap instances of `IMyClientAsync` in a `using` block since the compiler knows it implements `IDisposable`.

Answer (score 1):

```
IMyClientAsync GetClient()
{
   return new MyClient ();
}
```

Would need to be:

```
MyClient GetClient()
{
   return new MyClient ();
}
```

In order for the compiler to know it implements `IDisposable`.

As you have it in your question, `IMyClientAsync` does **not** implement `IDisposable`.

If that is not possible for your use case, you could also ensure your `IMyClientAsync` interface also implements `IDisposable`.